# Help understanding partitions on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, mount

After having issues installing Ubuntu on a computer i believe that i have created several partitions rather than simply one Ubuntu OS.  What I need is for there to be only one instance of Ubuntu on this computer with all of the available memory.

The output of sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           465,8G
├─sda1 vfat     512M /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4   461,5G /
└─sda3 swap     3,8G [SWAP]
sr0             624M

[output from gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBvzj.png)

I am hoping there is a way to simply merge the partitions without losing anything, but at worst I could try reinstalling Ubuntu again if needed, though some advice on how to not do this again would probably be needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the standard partition setup for a UEFI computer. No need to change it or reinstall.

Comment: The problem is that i am currently on sda3 and need to have access to the memory on sda2.  can i merge them?  If i do merge them will i lose anything ?

Comment: sda3 is the swap. You are not booted into that. sda2 is / (root). That is Ubuntu (in the sense that you are thinking of it). Swap is optional but generally used. the /boot/efi is needed to boot the computer.

Comment: I am attempting to use virtualbox and run an iso.  when attempting to run the iso , as base memory it requests 4096MB of memory.  I get an error that says "80% of the hosts 3.68Gig memroy is assigned to this VM and host cannot run OS "

This led me to believe that it was because of the partitions but if you think that i am wrong, could there be a work around

Comment: That has nothing to do with partitions, I'm sorry to say. And is too much for comments. :) I'm sure if you search the site you can find another on allocating memory to VM.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing disk partitions and physical memory. Your disk partitions look fine, although your swap partition may be a little small, for the limited physical memory that you have installed.

The problem that you're having is that you've requested that the guest OS use more of physical memory than what's available. You either need to reduce the 4096GB RAM for the guest OS, or install more physical memory.

Cheers, Al